# Selecting dynamiclly filled drop-down with in form using python

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to fill form on a website and now I run into a problem with dynamically-filled drop-down lists that are dependent on a previous selection.I have four drop-downs in a form which are dynamically populated and then user can submit the form.

Drop-down are :

```
  Continent                               
    -- Country                               #depends on continent
         -- state                                  #depends on Country
               --city                                      #depends on state
```

How can I select values from these drop-downs using python?

Comment: How you solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values are dynamically filled, you can't do that since mechanize won't take care of runnig the javascript code as it will happen when displaying the page in a web browser.

You have some alternatives:

- Send the POST request with the values from the form to simulate that it's been properly filled.
- Use something like selenium or windmill to drive a real web browser that executes the javascript code that you need to populate the drow-down widgets.